# tkhtmlview HTMLLabel change font size?

Tags: python, tkinter, html-parser

I want to use HTMLLabel in one of my Tkinter projects', but I dislike that the font size is hardcoded to 14. I want it to be 10 instead.

Adding the `font=("Calibri", 10)` does nothing to render font family or size.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel

html = "Some text! Always size 14 :("


root = Tk()
root.title('html')
root.geometry('300x300')

my_label = HTMLLabel(root, html=html, state="normal", font=("Calibri", 10))

my_label.pack(pady=20,
              padx=20,
              fill="both",
              expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

I have noticed there is a variable `FONT_SIZE` in the `Defs` method of the class module `html_parser.py`:

```
class Defs():
    DEFAULT_TEXT_FONT_FAMILY = (
        "Segoe ui", "Calibri", "Helvetica", "TkTextFont")
    FONT_SIZE = 14
    }
```

If I change `FONT_SIZE = 14` to
`FONT_SIZE = 10` in the sourced module, it works everywhere.

Does anyone know how to set my font size to 10 in my script without editing the imported `html_parser.py` module, as I would imagine it's not an appropriate practice to edit a module this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check setting the font size by the style. See the result:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
r=Tk()
r.title('Alles Normal')
r.geometry('280x430')
html_text='''
<h5 style="text-align: center;"><u>TOO</u></h5>
<p style="font-size: 12px;">Hello, my friends!
Are you fine!</p>
Yes, of course!
<p style="font-size: 18px;">I'm happy</p>
<p style="font-size: 25px;">Very happy</p>
'''
ml=HTMLLabel(r, html=html_text)
ml.fit_height()
ml.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill='both', expand=True)
r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i wanted to change the font-family to Courier, changing it in the html using the style attribute didn't do anything

So, changed the DEFAULT_TEXT_FONT_FAMILY constant in the Defs class along with writing it in the html inside the style tag

```
from tkhtmlview.html_parser import Defs

Defs.DEFAULT_TEXT_FONT_FAMILY = ("Courier")
```

Write in both the places and it will work